# Swift 2 iOS 9 Do Catch Try crashing with unexpected nil found

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, swift2, ios9

I'm trying to become familiar with the new `do catch` statements with swift 2 and iOS 9

My problem is that when an error occurs with NSURLSession, the data parameter returns nil, and error returns something. In iOS 8 this was expected functionality and we simply used if statements to find out whether or not Data was nil

However with `do` `catch`, there is the new `try` keyword which I thought was meant to see if something works, if it doesn't then default to whatever code is written in `catch`

However, because data is nil I am getting an unexpected crash. Is this expected functionality, why isn't `catch` being called when my `try` method fails?

I'm using NSURLSession to pull data from an API.

I create a dataTaskWith request like this:

```
 let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        print(request)
        print(response)
        print(error)

        do {

            let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
```

Crashes right here because data!  is nil.. because there was an NSURLSession error

```
            print(jsonResult)




        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    })
    task.resume()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `catch` only catches what a functions "throws".

`NSJSONSerialization` throws, but force unwrapping an empty Optional doesn't, it always crashes.

Use `if let` or the new `guard` function to safely unwrap your values.

```
do {
    if let myData = data, let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(myData, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
        print(jsonResult)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: So say I use a guard statement to unwrap data. If error contains and error, and data is nil, then the guard statement will exit the current scope and I won't see my error.. which I want to see. Right?

Comment: If you want to use `guard` you don't *have* to do it in `do catch`, so you can do it just before, inside your `task` for example, and benefit from the "error" variable given by `session.dataTaskWithRequest`. // Note: the "error" variable inside the catch is not the same variable, it's the generic variable automatically used by `catch`.

Comment: So on your `if let` statement, if data == nil, then the `try` will not be executed and therefore will not `throw`, and so `catch` won't be called, and so I won't get my error. Right? Wasn't the old `if error != nil { print(data) }` better than?

Comment: But the errors from data being nil and from NSJSONSerialization failing are not related. :) Nothing changes from before in functionality. You can always use `if let ... ELSE` to make a branch where you handle the "data" being nil, it's different from the `do try catch` you do for JSON.

Comment: AND sometimes mondays aren't the best day ever. Great. It makes sense.