# Read HTML file in Swift 2.0

Tags: html, string, error-handling, swift2

I am using the code below.

```
func getData(url: String) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: url) {
        do {
            let html = try NSString(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("HTML: \(html)")
        } catch {
            print("x")
        }

    }

}

getData("Google.com")
```

I need help with later printing out the variable 'html' and any other case printing out the error that forced the catch throw.  With the current code it prints out "x".  I want to print out why it forced that catch I can know what went wrong and why 'html' did not print.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift do-try-catch syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720497/swift-do-try-catch-syntax)

Comment: @EricD. I am trying to see if there a way to print out what forced that catch statement? I want to know like why didn't my code print out 'html' instead it printed out 'x'.

Comment: Replace `print("x")` with `print(error)`. This `error` variable is not yours, it's generated by the `do catch` mechanism. Try it. :) // Like in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32187781/2227743). // Next step: create your own error types as explained in the duplicate link.

Answer (score 0):

Create Enum field of ErrorType with error types and iterate through them with do ... catch syntax ... u have already answer on this topic:

[Swift do-try-catch syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720497/swift-do-try-catch-syntax)

Comment: how do I actually print out the error that happened.

Comment: i dont understand your question ? u want to print error where ?

Comment: Is there a way to print out what forced that catch statement? I want to know like why didn't my code print out 'html' instead it printed out 'x'.

Comment: well as i told u make enum with error types like enum MyErrors : ErrorType { case BadFile
case BadNetwork
}
and then u iterate through errors with do {
    let sandwich = try doSomeFunction(function)
    print("i did function")
} catch MyErrors.BadFile {
    print("Bad File")
} catch MyErrors.BadNetwork {
    print("Bad Error")
} catch {
    print("random error")
}

Comment: look at comment above that was what I was looking for the part print(error)