# parsing Json Array swift 2 error

Tags: json, swift2, xcode7

this code was function correctly but when i tried on swift 2, i start having this errors, does anyone know how to fix them? i already add the NSAppTransportSecurity to info list.
The app may be able to download a json array with images from server, but i'm not really sure how to do it on swift 2

[image: Xcode error]

I tried a lot of tutorials about swift 2 but didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 2 iOS 9 Do Catch Try crashing with unexpected nil found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187683/swift-2-ios-9-do-catch-try-crashing-with-unexpected-nil-found)

Answer (score 1):

Try this....Use do catch instead of if let

```
do {
    let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject, options:.MutableContainers) as? NSArray
    self.images = jsonResult
} catch let error as NSError {
     print(error)
}
```