# Crash without Internet

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am getting error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on this line when Internet is not connected.

```
let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary            // Line 


                self.dict = jsonData;

                self.array1 = (self.dict.objectForKey("results") as? NSMutableArray)!

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.table.reloadData()
                }


            } catch {

                print(error)
            }
        })
        task1.resume()
```

Please help Any help would be apperciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 2 iOS 9 Do Catch Try crashing with unexpected nil found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187683/swift-2-ios-9-do-catch-try-crashing-with-unexpected-nil-found)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens, because you force unwrap the `data`, which is always a bad idea, because you don't know if its `nil` or not.

To get around this, you need to check if data is nil, before you try serial the JSON:

```
// Checking if data is nil, and unwraping it
if let unwrappedData = data {
    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(unwrappedData, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary 
    // handle json here
}
```

or another way:

```
if data == nil {
    return 
}
// else, data is not nil
let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization...
```

Comment: You don't need the `!` on `unwrappedData`. I'll fix it because I'm going to edit your post to changed unwraped to unwrapped anyway.