# Error with JSON in Xcode7

Tags: json, swift, xcode7

I am getting an error on the following string :

```
let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData (ipxData, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &jsonError) as! [String: AnyObject]**
```

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var salaIng: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var salaG1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var salaG2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var salaVela: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cucina1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var corridoio1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var camera1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var disinpegno1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cameretta1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var disinpegno2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bagno1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var disinpegno3: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getipxData("http://192.168.1.201/api/xdevices.json?cmd=10")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func getipxData(urlstring: String) {
    let url = NSURL(string: urlstring)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) in

        if error == nil {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.setlabels(data)
            })
        } else {
            print("error occured-\(error)")
        }
    }

    task.resume()

}


func setlabels(ipxData: NSData){
    var jsonError: NSError?

    let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData (ipxData, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &jsonError) as! [String: AnyObject]
    //funzioni

    var in1 = json["IN1"] as! Int
    var in2 = json["IN2"] as! Int
    var in3 = json["IN3"] as! Int
    var in4 = json["IN4"] as! Int
    var in5 = json["IN5"] as! Int
    var in6 = json["IN6"] as! Int
    var in7 = json["IN7"] as! Int
    var in8 = json["IN8"] as! Int
    var in9 = json["IN9"] as! Int
    var in10 = json["IN10"] as! Int
```

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uT3S.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 2 iOS 9 Do Catch Try crashing with unexpected nil found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187683/swift-2-ios-9-do-catch-try-crashing-with-unexpected-nil-found)

Comment: There's an example of the new syntax in the linked I just pasted.

Comment: do  { 
    if  let myData = data ,  let jsonResult =  try  NSJSONSerialization . JSONObjectWithData ( myData , options :  [])  as ?  NSDictionary  { 
        print ( jsonResult ) 
    } 
}  catch  { 
    print ( error ) 
}

Comment: I'm sorry this ? with what I should change ? I'm sorry but I'm starting out with xcode