# Error: Could not cast value of type .. in JSON

Tags: swift, swift2

I want make a simple app about weather.

```
import Foundation

let getWeatherInfoUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.weather.com.cn/adat/sk/101280601.html")
let weatherInfo = NSData(contentsOfURL:getWeatherInfoUrl!)
if weatherInfo != nil
    {
    print(weatherInfo!) 
    let json: NSData = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(weatherInfo!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSData
    }else{
    print("error")
    }
```

This code main to get the data from url, then change to JSON.

It can run but the debug area show me this:

[image]

How do I solve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 2 iOS 9 Do Catch Try crashing with unexpected nil found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187683/swift-2-ios-9-do-catch-try-crashing-with-unexpected-nil-found)

Comment: The duplicate question title is different from yours but the answer contains an example for your problem.

Comment: The result of `JSONObjectWithData` is `Array` or `Dictionary` but never `NSData`

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting because you are casting json as `NSData`, however it should be either `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` based on the parse data. You can try with following code which gives you `NSDictionary` object as json and you can manipulate further to get the required information.

```
let getWeatherInfoUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.weather.com.cn/adat/sk/101280601.html")!
if let weatherInfo = NSData(contentsOfURL:getWeatherInfoUrl) {
    print(weatherInfo)
    let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(weatherInfo, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary
}
else{
    print("error")
}
```

Comment: But I want get some data from **JSON**,  when I code 'let info  = json.objectForKey("weatherinfo")',it notice *Use unresolved of identifler 'JSON'*.So how can i fix the bug.can u help me?

Comment: @B.Steven, you need to wrap json before accessing it. `let info = json!.objectForKey("weatherinfo")` this will work